# How to render an array from mysql in fpdf

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf of a query using the FPDF library but I can't do it, it only prints the first name of the array and doesn't go through the others, the query selects the students of the group brought with a post whose credits are greater than 0, would you be so kind to point out my mistake, thanks

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
include("conection.php");
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT student_qr FROM students WHERE student_group = ? AND student_credits > 0");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['seraching_group']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); 


$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf -> AddPage();

    $pdf -> SetFont('Arial', 'B', 11);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(0,134,255);
    $pdf->SetXY(10, 115);
    $pdf -> Cell(191.5,5,utf8_decode("Alumns"),0,1,'L',true);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
  $pdf-> Cell(110,50,$row["student_qr"], 1,1,'C', true);
  $pdf->Ln(); 
}

$pdf -> Output();

mysqli_close($con); 
header("Location:http://localhost/dinningRoom_08/reporte_prueba.php");
```

I want it to generate a PDF with each of the students of the selected group

Comment: Move the `$pdf -> Output();` out of the while loop?

Comment: Once you call [`$pdf->Output()`](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm), the PDF generation is completed, so it needs to be below the `mysqli_close($con)` call. You'll also most likely need to add [`$pdf->Ln();`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/ln.htm) instead. Additionally remove the `header` redirect and closing php tag `?>`, since the pdf is rendered inline by default.

Answer (score 0):

I was making the mistake of closing the pdf after the first traversal of the fix, with the help of my colleagues, the problem was solved and the code is functional after editing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).